# Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference on calling .datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have create and populated Jquery Datatable dynamically using Ajax. After Datatable got created, I am trying to access its row values but getting error like `Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference`. Here is the code adding which the above error is coming at loading time of the page, if I am not adding the page is rendering fine.

```
var tbtable = $('#SettingsDatatable').DataTable();
var dataa = tbtable.row($(this).closest("tr")).data();
```

Please help.

Comment: What is `this` in `$(this).closest("tr")` ...? If that is the code `this` would never contain a valid table element reference, and if it is not, for example part of some kind of event handler, please show your entire code that is relevant.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have created Datatable inside Ajax call to Webservice. Outside of Ajax I am adding the posted code. Is there any alternate of `this`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data for *all* rows (which it sounds like you do), you just need to change

```
var dataa = tbtable.row($(this).closest("tr")).data();
```

to

```
var dataa = tbtable.rows().data();
```

Your previous version is what you would use if you wanted to get a single row's data, but if that's the case, you have to actually call that from something that can identify what `this` is, where `this` refers to something within the `<tr>` element of the row whose data you want to retrieve.

Comment: I need to get individual row value.would request to please advice me by sharing a code snippet which would take it from tr.

Comment: @Lara What you already have is the way to get a single row's data, the issue is where you're calling it from. Can you clarify why you need a single row, which row it should be (the one they click on, the first row, etc) and for what purpose you're using that data? That information may make it easier for me to tell you how to do it.